# How would you get a list of all the applications in use at your company?

Tags: configuration-management

I'm responsible for maintaining a list of all the applications in my company (about 250). The range is from HR systems that track 80k employees, to manufacturing-type systems responsible for hundreds of millions of dollars of revenue, to web applications with a small user base and not a lot of risk associated to them going down.

The technologies are mostly split between SAP, .Net, and Java, but we have legacy examples of just about everything else you can imagine.

The point of the list is to be able to manage risk and identify opportunities for improvement. For instance, when we find systems that are responsible for core business functionality that are written in clipper, we try to find some money to re-write them. We call the picture of the high-risk apps in the landscape the "heat map".

The list is pretty simple - It really just needs the name, description, ID, DB platform, App platform (ex, SAP, .Net, Java on Weblogic, Mainframe, etc), key interfaces, and key services.

Anyone have any experience building / maintaining a list like this? What should I keep in mind?

Comment: Your question only seems to mention network based apps.  It that all you're responsible for or are you supposed to list desktop apps too?

Comment: My apologies - I'm responsible for all apps from a $.5b SAP implementation to desktop apps used by half a dozen people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use software from Centennial, see: [their website](http://www.centennial-software.com/)

This allows us to keep track of what is installed, and helps ensure our licencing requirements are up to date.

This won't give all the information you require, but should give an initial list which you can then work from, and flesh out.

Be sure to list application sponsors, as well as processes which each application is involved in.